# Signalr logging out user when navigating from one page to another

Tags: c#, signalr, .net-4.5

I've got health monitoring set up and I'm receiving the error below.

In the Safari browser I'm receiving the Signalr error below, I have not received this error in other browsers.

What is so strange is that when I navigate from one page to the next is that this error will actually **log out the user and send them to the log in page** and this is after they're logged in.

Anyone got any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
    ** Application Information **
---------------
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/15/ROOT-1-130329090058437500
Trust level: Full
Application Virtual Path: /
Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\alumcloud.com\ Machine name: AFBS-WEB1


** Events **
---------------
Event code: 3005
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
Event time: 12/30/2013 2:32:24 PM
Event time (UTC): 12/30/2013 8:32:24 PM
Event ID: a243cb6cf5e24be8bfa0d1bec6e77812 Event sequence: 211 Event occurrence: 2 Event detail code: 0

Process information:
    Process ID: 924
    Process name: w3wp.exe
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Exception information:
    Exception type: System.InvalidOperationException
    Exception message: Unrecognized user identity.  The user identity cannot change during an active SignalR connection.

Request information:
    Request URL: http://www.alumcloud.com/signalr/abort?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=xHLBS1B7LGOjUWkVos29QlnBuMwBfTg%2BNQuEDmrhy%2BADr45Yw0iDIHCh1nX8omumVA%2F1eFje774jLVE%2BOId8ab4cJJ3r1hZ8DGlq23yA0WsGk0biYy7JYmnxM2hqu2cw&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22alumchathub%22%7D%5D
    Request path: /signalr/abort
    User host address: 71.244.XXX.XXX
    User: XXXXXXXXXXXX
    Is authenticated: True
    Authentication Type: Forms
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Thread information:
    Thread ID: 22
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
    Is impersonating: False
    Stack trace:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.GetConnectionId(HostContext context, String connectionToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(HostContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ProcessRequest(HostContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a request was made to /signalr/abort?..., it appears that `connection.stop` must have been called. This can either happen because you called `connection.stop` directly or because SignalR indirectly called `connection.stop` for you as the user navigated away from the page using the SignalR connection.

The exception message ("Unrecognized user identity.  The user identity cannot change during an active SignalR connection.") indicates that the user's `IIdentity` changed between the SignalR connection starting and stopping.

This can happen for multiple reasons, perhaps the most common of which is the ASP.NET forms auth cookie expiring causing the user's identity to become unauthenticated. Other causes could be the user logging off, logging in, or switching users while the SignalR connection is ongoing.

SignalR does not allow the user's `IIdentity` to change during an ongoing connection in order to help prevent CSRF attacks.

The request to /signalr/abort?... is an Ajax request being made by the SignalR client. The SignalR client doesn't take any action based on the response of the abort request, so I wouldn't expect a failed abort to cause any sort of redirect.